# GENEXUS 17 -- Failed: GAM Data Initialization Failed: Integrated Security Data Initialization

Tags: genexus

I have a KB that uses GAM, I'm trying to create it with the database zero and start GAM and create the tables and everything, the tables even create, but when it fails to register everything in the tables, I have already entered the ID and admin of the repository used in the other database that works, but the error persists, the database I am using is MySQL and the database that the application works in the other environment that already has data in the database is SQLserver.

[Error ocurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp084.png)

Comment: If you perform the following action:

Tools / GeneXus Access Manager / Create Tables

What error does it give you?

Comment: The error I mentioned above occurs, it creates the tables but when registering it gives this error.

Comment: Corrigindo o banco é  Posgresql

Answer (score 1):

Check in your environment the following properties:

- [Reorganize server tables](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8955,Reorganize%20server%20tables%20property) must be set to **Yes**.
- In case you have [Enable Integrated Security property](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?14706,Enable%20Integrated%20Security%20property) =
  **True**, check that [Keep GAM database updated](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?21453,Keep%20GAM%20database%20updated%20property) is  set to **True**.

Comment: Tentei isso também, o erro persiste, o banco na verdade é PostgresSQL.